# Динамическая подгрузка и обновление классов в Java

Tags: классы, java

Возможно ли в Java реализовать динамическое обновление класса?
К примеру, в приложение подгружается класс, но через какое-то время нужно его обновить на более новую модификацию, не перезапуская все приложение целиком.

Comment: что значит "нужно его обновить на более новую модификацию"? Что за "более новая модификация" и что подразумевается под "обновить"?

Comment: Был, например, подгружен класс, который выполняет 15 функций, но один из партнеров решил внести в него корректировки, например, добавил новые 2 функции и изменил пару других, нужен способ, чтобы старый класс был выгружен из памяти и заменен новым модифицированным классом "на лету".

Comment: эмм..а как вы себе это представляете? Ну допустим, у вас есть некий класс, который имел раньше 8 методов, а сейчас имеет 10 методов. Скажем, вы каким-то чудесным образом его "Запихнули" в память уже работающей программы "на лету". А какой в этом смысл? Ведь вся остальная ваша программа знать не знает об этих двух новых методах, следовательно, нужно точно так же "на лету" менять и всю остальную вашу программу, чтобы она "знала", что нужно делать с обновленным классом чтобы он правильно работал. А следовательно, надо перезапускать ее

Comment: Система реализована форматом API, есть главный класс, из которого по названию можно вызвать любую функцию из подгруженных классов, общение непосредственно с самим сайтом партнера через socket. Просто перезагружать сервер с кучей активных соединений с другими серверами это очень большая морока и какое-то время, в которое система будет недоступна. Вот и задумались о таких извращениях, как обновление класса. 
Это вообще в принципе возможно в Java или стоит перевести усилия в создание функций, которые уведомят сервера о перезагрузке и правильно отработают данные перед ней?

Comment: я не претендую на то, чтобы быть истиной в последней инстанции, но скорее всего подобные фокусы невозможны - каким-то чудодейственным образом в уже запущенное и висящее в памяти приложение "внедрить" какую-то новую логику - это что-то из разряда полуфантастических колдунств, которые, кстати, будь они даже возможны, обрубались бы антивирусом. 

Кстати, не очень понятно, зачем перезагружать весь сервер - почему нельзя перезапустить собственно программу?

Comment: Именно про программу я и говорил, но из-за большого количества модулей перезапуск её будет в течении пары минут, а все сайты за которые она отвечает в этот момент окажутся неактивными

Comment: кажется мне, что Вы изобретаете эрланг. Там подобное возможно. Прямо на лету. Новые клиенты используют новый код, старые - старый. Как только всех старых клиентов обслужат, уборщик мусора подчищает код в памяти.

Comment: @DreamChild, на самом деле такие фокусы вполне реальны. Для Java есть замечательный инструмент JRebel, мониторящий изменения классов и перезагружающий их буквально на лету. Инструмент, правда, платный, но я где-то фидел бесплатные (хоть и значительно менее функциональные) аналоги. Гуглить по фразе "java hotswap".

Comment: @fori1ton насколько я понимаю, ТС хочет подменять уже загруженное в память  и работающее приложение новым кодом. Инструменты, о которых вы упоминаете - это действительно то, о чем я говорю выше? Просто мне кажется, что подобные действия не очень хорошо согласуются с принципами безопасности

Comment: @DreamChild, JRebel умеет перезагружать классы в работающем приложении. Обычно JRebel и подобные инструменты используются при разработке, чтобы не перезагружать тяжёлые приложения после каждого изменения, наверняка использовать его в продакшне не лучшая идея, как в плане безопасности, так и в плане быстродействия. Однако факт остаётся фактом - перезагрузка классов в работающем приложении возможна. Кстати, вторая ссылка в Гугле ведёт на opensource аналог JRebel - Hotswap Agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да какие проблемы то?

```
ClassLoader classLoader = MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
Class myNewClass = classLoader.loadClass("mydomain.MyNewClass");
```

Предполагается, что объектник `MyNewClass` лежит в `CLASSPATH`, хотя можно и без этого. Можно даже скомпилировать `MyNewClass` из исходников :)

Далее имея переменную `myNewClass` с помощью рефлексии уже можно перенумеровать новые методы и вызвать какой нужно.

**Update:**

Простенькие примеры рефлексии:

```
Method[] methods=myNewClass.getMethods(); //список публичных методов класса
Method method=myNewClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMyMethod", String.class); //получаем метод getMyMethod(String )
Constructor[] constructors=myNewClass.getConstructors(); //список конструкторов
//ну и т.п.
```

Далее уже надеюсь понятно? Есть конструктор, есть методы: создаем объект, вызываем его методы ну и т.д.

Comment: Можно пример кода про рефлексию и нумерацию?

Comment: Загрузчик снова класс не загрузит если его уже загружал и если его загружали  или его загружали загрузчики выше по иерархии.

Т.е. нужно для нового класса новый загрузчик, который об этом классе не знает.

Comment: @Максим я к тому, что на java можно построить модульную систему (есть, например, архитектура OSGI), где модуль можно будет выгружать и загружать на лету.

Это не так просто, лучше взять готовую.

Comment: @Vladislav Pyatkov - да вы правы, загрузчик загружает классы только один раз. Чтобы он обновлял загруженный ранее класс, надо писать кастомным загрузчик - это чуток побольше кода. У меня же приведен код загрузки нового класса.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте интерфейсы и классы их реализующие, например, интерфейс IFunctional и их реализующие классы Functional10, Functional11, Functional12 и т.д. Класс загружайте класслоадером, имя загружаемого класса прописывайте в конфиг-файле.